# how to find stationary point of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, variational-calculus

I am quite new, how can I find minumum, maximum or saddle point the following multivariable function by using mathematica
$f(x,y)= 2x^3 +6xy^2 −3y^3 −150x$

Comment: Isn't you $x$ derivative always positive? so no min/max/saddle?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I updated the question.

Comment: [Saddle Points and Inflection Points: Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SaddlePointsAndInflectionPoints/); and using `Minimize` and `Maximize` shows that your exemplary function does not have a min/max.

Comment: Is it Mathematica software question or general math question?

Comment: See the "Applications" section of the docs for [`Grad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html#1433577601).